# Indexing Python deque inside of lists

Tags: python, list, deque

I tried to work with a list of deques and was not able to to append a value to a single deque by indexing it.
It looks like the following:

```
>>> l_deque = [deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3)] * 5
>>> l_deque
[deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0])]

>>> l_deque[0]
deque([0, 0, 0])
```

So far so good. But when I try to append a value to a single deque it appends it to every deque:

```
>>> l_deque[0].append(1)
>>> l_deque
[deque([0, 0, 1]),
 deque([0, 0, 1]),
 deque([0, 0, 1]),
 deque([0, 0, 1]),
 deque([0, 0, 1])]
```

I expected something like this:

```
[deque([0, 0, 1]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0]),
 deque([0, 0, 0])]
```

Do you have an idea where I took the wrong turn?
Thanks

Edit:
Thanks guys,
Changing it to

```
    >>> l = [deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3), 
            deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3), 
            deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3), 
            deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3), 
            deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3)]
```

did the job.
Ugly but effective.

Comment: Classic. When you do `[x] * 5` you create a list `[x, x, x, x, x]` where every `x` point to the same place in memory, if `x` is a referenced object like `deque`. So when you modify one of your deques you modify all of them.

Comment: `[deque([0] * 3, maxlen = 3)] * 5` creates a list with *five references to the same deque object*.

Comment: @VisioN I'm not sure what you mean by "a referenced object like deque", but I think it is important to be clear that this behavior is the same *for all objects*, i.e. *for anything* in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That doesn't work this way for primitives, e.g. `[0] * 3` will create a list of integer objects by value.

Comment: `[deque([0] * 3, maxlen=3) for _ in range(5)]` for a less ugly solution…

Comment: @VisioN no, that is not true. There **is no such thing as primitive values in Python**. *Everything is an object*. the `int` object created by the literal `1000` is *an object in the exact same way a `list` is an object*. Python doesn't distinguish between "reference types and value types" like Java, Python is a purely object-oriented language. Indeed, just prove it to yourself: `set(map(id, [1000]*5))`